# See if string variable is empty. If it's empty add a value to it

Tags: vbscript

I'm reading in energy data from an windfarm via a CSV file.
And passing it out in a new CSV file. this file need to have values to it.

But when sometimes the windfarm is offline and the my variables will be empty.
So I need a way to see if there are empty and the assign a "0" to it.
CSV file values get read by an OPC server so there need to be values in it.

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim objFile, strNewestFile, dtmMax
For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder("C:\CSV\Test\CSVOriginal").Files
    If objFile.DateLastModified > dtmMax Then
        dtmMax = objFile.DateLastModified
        strNewestFile = objFile.Path
    End If
Next

objFSO.GetFile(strNewestFile).Copy "C:\CSV\Test\CSVFlytt\Data.csv"

Const ForReading = 1

Dim arrCSVData, arrCSVDataOpc(10,1)
Dim strData, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4, Y4, X5, Y5, X6, Y6, X7, Y7, X8, Y8, X9, Y9, X10, Y10, X11, Y11
Dim X20, X21, X22, X23, X24, X25

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\CSV\Test\CSVFlytt\Data.csv", ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strNextLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If Len(strNextLine) > 0 Then
        strLine = strNextLine
    End If
Loop

objFile.Close

'WScript.Echo strLine

strData = strLine
arrCSVData = Split(strData , ";")
For i = LBound(arrCSVData) To UBound(arrCSVData)
    'WScript.Echo arrCSVData(i)

    X1 = "Wm2"
    Y1 = arrCSVData(2)

    X2 = "°C"
    Y2 = arrCSVData(4)

    X3 = "m/s"
    Y3 = arrCSVData(6)

    X4 = "VR1 kWh"
    Y4 = arrCSVData(9)  
    X5 = "VR1 W"
    Y5 = arrCSVData(18)

    X6 = "VR2 kWh"
    Y6 = arrCSVData(30) 
    X7 = "VR2 W"
    Y7 = arrCSVData(39)

    X8 = "VR3 kWh"
    Y8 = arrCSVData(51) 
    X9 = "VR3 W"
    Y9 = arrCSVData(60)

    X20 = CSng(Y4)
    X21 = CSng(Y6)
    X22 = CSng(Y8)

    X10 = "Total kWh"
    Y10 = (X20 + X21 + Y8)

    X23 = CSng(Y4)
    X24 = CSng(Y7)
    X25 = CSng(Y9)

    X11 = "Total W"
    Y11 = (X23 + X24 + X25)
Next

arrCSVDataOpc(0,0)= X1
arrCSVDataOpc(0,1)= Y1
arrCSVDataOpc(1,0)= X2
arrCSVDataOpc(1,1)= Y2
arrCSVDataOpc(2,0)= X3
arrCSVDataOpc(2,1)= Y3
arrCSVDataOpc(3,0)= X4
arrCSVDataOpc(3,1)= Y4
arrCSVDataOpc(4,0)= X5
arrCSVDataOpc(4,1)= Y5
arrCSVDataOpc(5,0)= X6
arrCSVDataOpc(5,1)= Y6
arrCSVDataOpc(6,0)= X7
arrCSVDataOpc(6,1)= Y7
arrCSVDataOpc(7,0)= X8
arrCSVDataOpc(7,1)= Y8
arrCSVDataOpc(8,0)= X9
arrCSVDataOpc(8,1)= Y9
arrCSVDataOpc(9,0)= X10
arrCSVDataOpc(9,1)= Y10
arrCSVDataOpc(10,0)= X11
arrCSVDataOpc(10,1)= Y11
arrCSVDataOpc(10,0)= X11
arrCSVDataOpc(10,1)= Y11

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim filesys, testfile 
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set testfile = oFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\CSV\Test\OPC\data.csv", True)
testfile.WriteLine X1 & ";" & Y1
testfile.WriteLine X2 & ";" & Y2
testfile.WriteLine X3 & ";" & Y3
testfile.WriteLine X4 & ";" & Y4
testfile.WriteLine X5 & ";" & Y5
testfile.WriteLine X6 & ";" & Y6
testfile.WriteLine X7 & ";" & Y7
testfile.WriteLine X8 & ";" & Y8
testfile.WriteLine X9 & ";" & Y9
testfile.WriteLine X10 & ";" & Y10
testfile.WriteLine X11 & ";" & Y11
testfile.Close
```

Comment: like: `Y1 = iif(arrCSVData(2)="","0",arrCSVData(2))` ?    [check the iif function](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3)

Comment: What exactly is empty? The array? Or the fields of the array? Also, do you actually mean [`Empty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) when you say "empty"?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ - VBScript doesn't have the `IIf()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks to your code:

- use `Option Explicit` statement (the 1st line of code);
- use `On Error Goto 0` statement (the 2nd line of code) instead of `On Error Resume Next`;
- redefining `Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` seems to be superabundant: the first occurrence of this statement should suffice;
- I'd use `strNextLine = Trim( objFile.ReadLine)` for next `If Len(strNextLine) > 0` test accuracy;
- `If UBound(arrCSVData) < 60 Then Redim Preserve arrCSVData(60)` to ensure all used array items are present and to prevent the VBScript runtime error `Subscript out of range: '[number: #]'`;
- omit the `For i = LBound(arrCSVData) To UBound(arrCSVData)` loop (i.e. this line and appropriate `Next`): it loops *the same code* `UBound(arrCSVData)+1` times;
- use e.g. `Y9 = replaceEmpty(arrCSVData(60), "0")` if the `replaceEmpty` function is  defined as follows:

---

```
Function replaceEmpty( sValueToTest, defaultVal)
  If IsNull( sValueToTest) Then
    replaceEmpty = ""
  Else
    replaceEmpty = CStr(sValueToTest)
  End If
  If Trim( replaceEmpty) = "" Then replaceEmpty = defaultVal
End Function
```

Comment: `Empty` and `Null` are not the same.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I know the difference among `Empty` (== uninitialized) vs. `Null` (== no valid data) vs. `""` (== string of zero length, commonly named _empty string_). The `If IsNull( sValueToTest) ...` check is here for the sake of _bullet-proof_ code because the `CStr` function raises a VBScript runtime error if its argument expression is `Null` while `CStr( Empty)` is valid and results to `""`.

Comment: Does the person reading your answer know it too? If not I'd consider it worth explaining.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop when you assign a value to the variables from the array with your data.   Change the code as per the example below.  ie for every data item that can potentially be equal to "" when you need it to be 0 change the corresponding line

ie change

```
Y1 = arrCSVData(2)
```

to

```
Y1 = iif( arrCSVData(2)="",0 ,arrCSVData(2) )
```

Also, I was wondering why you are using `on error resume next`.